# TypeError - can't quote Rack::Session::SessionId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, typeerror, rack, internal-server-error

I am getting a mystifying error when trying to access Questions#Show. Anytime I redirect to the View, I get a 500 internal server error. According to my server trace, the issue is in the Questions controller in 'set_question'

```
Started GET "/questions/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-01 18:57:34 +0100
Processing by QuestionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Question Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:105:in `set_question'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms | Allocations: 3861)

TypeError - can't quote Rack::Session::SessionId:
```

However I am not quite sure what is wrong with it

**Questions Controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  impressionist :actions => [:show], unique: [:session_hash]

  def index
  end

  def show
    @answers = @question.answers.includes(:user).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def edit
    authorize @question
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'You have successfully asked a question!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    authorize @question
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @question
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @questions_url, notice: 'Question successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Anyone familiar with this TypeError? I have tried Google and StackOverflow and haven't seen any hints
I have used virtually identical code for other models, however this is the only one which gives me a TypeError

**Stack Trace**

```
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:231:in `_quote'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:18:in `quote'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/collectors/substitute_binds.rb:17:in `add_bind'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:703:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_BindParam'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:31:in `visit'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:611:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Equality'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:31:in `visit'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:790:in `block in inject_join'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788:in `each'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788:in `each_with_index'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788:in `inject_join'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:578:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_And'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:31:in `visit'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:790:in `block in inject_join'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788:in `each'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788:in `each_with_index'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788:in `inject_join'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:181:in `collect_nodes_for'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:161:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb:28:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:128:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:127:in `each'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:127:in `inject'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:127:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb:23:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:31:in `visit'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:18:in `compile'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:34:in `to_sql_and_binds'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:99:in `select_all'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:12:in `select_all'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:77:in `select_one'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:317:in `block in exists?'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/relation.rb:828:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:317:in `exists?'
impressionist (1.6.1) app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:103:in `check_unique_impression?'
impressionist (1.6.1) app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:99:in `check_impression?'
impressionist (1.6.1) app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:94:in `unique?'
impressionist (1.6.1) app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:44:in `impressionist_subapp_filter'
impressionist (1.6.1) app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb:7:in `block in impressionist'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:110:in `block in run_callbacks'
public_activity (1.6.4) lib/public_activity/utility/store_controller.rb:27:in `store_controller_for_public_activity'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:139:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
rack-mini-profiler (1.1.5) lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:104:in `block in profile_method'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack-pjax (1.1.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
bullet (6.1.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:15:in `call'
remotipart (1.4.4) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:17:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:269:in `context'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:263:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (1.1.5) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:296:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of authentication system in place? It could be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38039

Comment: Aside from user authentication I don't have any system in place. I saw that post but wasn't able to link it to my problem. But maybe I took the wrong approach

Comment: Can you include the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Updated the trace

Comment: Thats not a stack trace, thats just more of the logs which tell us nothing about what happened. Usually you can see the stack trace by looking at the error page that rails renders in development. https://gorails.com/episodes/debugging-how-to-interpret-a-stacktrace

Comment: Sorry got my logs mixed up. Updated with the trace

Comment: You have `Question.find(params[:id])` but I don't see `:id` anywhere in your permitted parameters. Not sure why you aren't seeing a denied param in the web server log.

Comment: @Beartech you don't need to permit the id :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there is nothing wrong with your `set_question` method. The error says: `TypeError - can't quote Rack::Session::SessionId:` and that is happening in `impressionist :actions => [:show], unique: [:session_hash]`.

I haven't used this gem so can't exactly tell you how to counter that error but to prove my point, if you comment this line (line 3) in your controller, it will work.

You need to read more about implementing this gem to resolve it.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix this I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Tyler he commented that line which i told him to. Try that

Comment: @Tyler session_hash causes the problem

Answer (score 7):

I succeeded in reproducing the same exception. Perhaps your code or the gem you're using is running a query with `session.id`.

**Solution**

If your code uses `session.id` to identify a user, you should convert it to a String before using it.

```
# Bad
user = User.find_by(session_id: session.id)
# => TypeError can't quote Rack::Session::SessionId

# Good
user = User.find_by(session_id: session.id.to_s)
# Success!
```

If your code doesn't run a query by `session.id`, you should be suspicious of gems that insert processing in the middle of a rack session.

**Steps to debug**

This code is running in `Rails 5.2.4.2`.

```
# In controller
def new
  logger.info "class=#{session.id.class} to_s=#{session.id.to_s}"
end

# The log for the above code
# INFO -- class=Rack::Session::SessionId to_s=adf8...9af0 <- a long string
```

If you run a query by `session.id`, you get the `TypeError`.

```
SomethingModel.where(session_id: session.id).to_a
# => TypeError can't quote Rack::Session::SessionId
```

Answer (score 5):

Replacing the following code in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '....'
```

with

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '....'
```

fixed the **TypeError can't quote Rack::Session::SessionId** issue for me.

Note: make sure to replace the '....' with your own key.

Answer (score 0):

The session hash is string in impressionist but our session is stored with id if we are using device. Not sure with this impressionist gem but following solved my problem:

```
impressionist :actions => [:show], unique: [:impressionable_type,:impressionable_id,:session_hash.to_s]
```